# Can I install a PCI graphics card on a motherboard that has onboard graphics?

Tags: graphics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an old computer which has an "M5A88-V EVO" Asus motherboard with onboard "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4250]" graphics card.
The graphics card is no longer supported by any Linux kernal newer than my "3.13.0-93-generic" version.
MY QUESTION is: can I install a new graphics card on this motherboard and then upgrade my OS to the latest version of Ubuntu and the latest version of Firefox?
I tried installing Firefox version 104, but it hangs and it crashes on shutdown. I have been having lots of issues with websites not supporting Firefox version 66, which I had prior to trying version 104 of Firefox.
So, the question is, can I install a new graphics card in a PCI slot and somehow disable the onboard Radeon graphics hardware?
I thought of just replacing the entire computer, but I don't want to spend $1,500 or more for a new one.

Comment: Troubleshooting the Firefox problem ultimately led to them saying to upgrade my graphics card.

Comment: Firefox latest LTS being **91** todate. I would give a chance to it preferably to your 104 before anything else.

Comment: I will try using Firefox 91 first.  Thanks @MC68020

Comment: It seems to be working on version 91.  I had to create a new profile when I started up on version 91.  Then I copied the logins.json and key4.db files from the old profile's directory into the new profile's direcotry and it seems to be working.  Yay, I don't have to buy a new computer!  :)

Comment: Happy it worked. Well… you know… my motherboard is one year older than yours… and nevertheless running troublefree linux-5.4 + kde-5.23… so… next time you are being told you should buy new hardware… just remember that… you are not a quiche-eater. ;-) BTW, before your preferred websites start whining when seeing your 91, learn how to tweak its user-agent string… ;-)

Comment: Tweaking the user-agent string- I will look into that. Sneaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can install a graphics card in your PCI slot and disable the on-board video adapter.  You'll have to disable the old graphics card through the BIOS.  Check your systems manual to figure out how to get into the BIOS and disable the grapics adapter.